# Направление силы в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочу,  чтобы когда я нажимал на лкм на платформе, то объект перемещался в данную точку с помощью силы. Но он некорректно вычисляет направление.

```
void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "grownd")
            {
                Instantiate(spawnTarget, hit.point, Quaternion.identity);    
                cube.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(hit.point,ForceMode.Impulse); 
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: А ты выведи в консоль координаты которые ты ловишь при нажатии мышью в пространстве. Попробуй добавить в условии if Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100). Когда-то давно реализовывал движение персонажа, вот этой сотки тогда не хватило )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На то есть 2 причины.

1. Instantiate и собственно точка приложения удара - одна и та же позиция. Очевидно, это не правильно.
2. В методе AddForce первый параметр не точка, куда будет направляется объект, а вектор силы. [Подробнее про AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html)

Рабочий код будет выглядеть так:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
  RaycastHit hit;
  var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

  if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
  {
    if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "grownd")
    {
      var initPoss = Vector3.zero;

      Instantiate(spawnTarget, initPoss, Quaternion.identity);

      var direction = hit.point - spawnTarget.transform.position;

      spawnTarget.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(direction, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
  }
}
```

P.S. в имени объекта "grownd" опечатка:)